# How do I escape spaces when using bash history interaction?

Tags: bash, command-history, escape-characters

Is it possible to escape a space for input on a command? I want to do this:

```
!git\ clone
```

I love using `!` to run past commands but not being able to use the space often limits the functionality.

Comment: I'd've thought that would have worked.  But you might have to escape the escape (`!git\\ clone`).  Failing that, you can use reverse history search (`^Rgit clone`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
!?git clone
```

From `man bash`:

> ```
>  !?string[?]
> ```
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list containing string.  The trailing `?` may be omitted if string is followed immediately by a newline.

Also try <kbd>Alt + .</kbd> that repeats the last argument of the previous command (and pressing it again moves to the preceding command), and <kbd>Alt + Ctrl + y</kbd> which repeats the first argument of the previous command, or `n`-th if preceded by <kbd>Alt + n</kbd>.